# What types of x86 and x86-64 Windows software will not run on ARM-powered "Always Connected" Windows 10 PCs?

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, compatibility, arm, x86

Some PC manufacturers have announced Qualcomm Snapdragon 835-powered "Always Connected" PCs running an ARM version of Windows 10 S. Users will be able to upgrade to an ARM version of Windows 10 Pro, which will unlock the ability to side load applications, including x86 applications, which will run on these PCs via x86 emulation. It has been said, however, that not all software written for x86 and x86-64 Windows PCs will run on these "Always Connected" ARM-powered Windows 10 PCs.

I am not asking for a complete list of software titles that won't run. What I want to know is what are the specific requirements or restrictions that means that certain software  won't run.

I'm asking in order to help readers of this question decide if they likely will want or need to run such software, which may disqualify the purchase of these devices for those readers.

Answer (score 0):

According to [The Next Web](https://thenextweb.com/gadgets/2017/12/07/microsoft-qualcomms-always-connected-pcs-explained/),

> you will still be able to run most traditional software, so long as it comes with a 32-bit (x86) version. Software that are exclusively 64-bit will not work (unless it was designed specifically for ARM processors) but those are pretty rare. According to a Microsoft Spokesperson:
>   The emulation technology supports x86 applications. We do not emulate 64-bit applications, the majority of which are AAA Games. Additionally, the emulation technology does not emulate applications that require kernel-mode drivers (e.g. some anti-virus applications). We are working on an ARM64 SDK that will enable developers to author applications for ARM64 and we’ll have more news to share in the future.

According to [The Verge](https://www.theverge.com/2017/12/5/16737288/microsoft-windows-10-qualcomm-arm-laptops-launch),

> 64-bit Windows apps aren’t supported yet (developers will be able to recompile them in the future), and Microsoft isn’t supporting apps that use kernel mode drivers. That means most third-party antivirus software won’t be compatible, and the vast majority of games that use anti-cheat software will also not work correctly.

Comment: Now that I know that apps that use kernel mode drivers aren't supported, the next question is "what are some applications that use kernel mode drivers?" I asked that question separately -- superuser.com/questions/1276686/… -- and the question was immediately put on hold for being "too broad". I gather from the fact that this question was placed on hold for being too broad that there is potentially a lot of x86 software that uses kernel mode drivers, software that those ARM-powered "Always Connected" Windows 10 PCs will not, in their current state, be able to run.

Comment: One question left unaddressed by the Microsoft spokesperson is whether ARM-powered "Always Connected" Windows 10 PCs will support kernel mode drivers that have been compiled for ARM. Obviously, in their current state, they will not support kernel-mode drivers that have been compiled for x86 or for x86-64.